# Cannot connect to oracle database

Tags: sqlexception, oracle12c

**I am trying to connect to oracle database 12c using java in eclipse.
This is the exception that keeps getting caught.**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DBHelper.makeConnection(DBHelper.java:31)
    at Main.main(Main.java:37)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:246)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:161)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    ... 13 more
```

**Below is what i've done**

**main.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] arg) throws SQLException{

        DBHelper dbconn = new DBHelper("system", "reborn78");
        Connection conn = dbconn.makeConnection();


        ResultSet result = dbconn.runQuery(conn, "SELECT A,B FROM NEWS");

        System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;


public class DBHelper {

    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCL"; 

    public DBHelper(String userName, String passWord) throws SQLException{
        Driver myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver( myDriver );
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;     
    }


    public Connection makeConnection() throws SQLException{
          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.setProperty("user", this.userName);
          props.setProperty("password", this.passWord);


          return DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,props);




    }

    public ResultSet runQuery(Connection conn, String sqlQuery) throws SQLException{
        PreparedStatement preStatement;     
        ResultSet result;

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            statement.execute(sqlQuery);
            result = preStatement.executeQuery();
            return result;


    }
}
```

**below is my listener.ora file**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\Usama\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\app\Usama\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\app\Usama\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

**below is my tnsnames.ora file**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\Usama\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

SQL is connected using sqlplus and the listener running and connected to sql developer as well!
Below is the link to pictures
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vbv0gkfcz2g59t5/AACtIVR1-bIen99DNN4HDsWaa?dl=0

**I have wasted three days getting this right, i was able to get it to work yesterday but today when i restarted my system, the same error is back. I have tried everything available but nothing seems to work today.
Thanks in advance**

Comment: Is your Oracle server running locally? Is it running at all?

Comment: Yes, did you check the pictures attached?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2i5xp87vam97779/sql%20developer%20running%20and%20connected.jpg?dl=0

Please check this, i'm sure it is running

Comment: SQL\*Plus is connecting locally, not through the listener. What are the settings in SQL Developer? Just to check, does localhost still resolve to 127.0.0.1 (in your hosts file)? BTW, it is better to copy the text from your command window into the question, rather than linking to,images.

Comment: yes yes localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1, like i said it was working yesterday only. How do i check my sql developer settings?

Comment: i cannot access http://localhost:5500/em either. I wonder if that has got anything to do with this.

Comment: Figured it out. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.

I was able to get it to run by re-configuring the database using database configuration assistant and then configuring the net services by net configuration assistant.

Turns out, as I understand, it is the only way to start the services needed to connect via a listener. I have to do it manually and test the net connection in the net configuration assistant every time i restart the system.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue and its solution? It may be helpful for future visitors who have the same problem.

Comment: I was able to get it to run by re-configuring the database using database configuration assistant and then configuring the net services by net configuration assistant. Turns out, as I understand, it is the only way to start the services needed to connect via a listener. I have to do it manually and test the net connection in the net configuration assistant every time i restart the system.